Can embedded subsurfaces give torsion in quotient?
Consider an orientable surface $\Sigma$ with genus $g$ and positive number of boundary components $b>0$. Now, embed the orientable surfaces $\Sigma_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$ in $\Sigma$ (with corresponding genus $g_i$ and boundary components $b_i$). The embeddings are pair-wise disjoint.
The operation that I want to take is not the quotient, but it is very similar: For every $i=1,\dots,n$, consider $\Sigma_i\subseteq \Sigma$ and take its cone. More precisely,
$$ \frac{\Sigma_i\times[0,1]}{(x,1)\sim(y,1)} $$
and identify $\Sigma_i\times\{0\}$ with $\Sigma_i\subseteq\Sigma$.
After doing this for every $i$, we are left with a space $\Sigma'$.
Question: Under what circumstances has $H_1(\Sigma')$ torsion? Also, when is $\pi_1(\Sigma')$ not a free group?
Examples are very welcomed.

Are there any hidden assumptions about the relation between each $\Sigma_i$ and the boundary $\partial\Sigma$? It would not affect the answer but it would affect the proof in a small way.

The fundamental group $\pi_1(\Sigma')$ can be expressed as a free product of free groups and fundamental groups of closed surfaces. From this description you can conclude that there is no torsion in $H_1(\Sigma')$. Also, from the construction you can identify whether or not any of the free factors is the fundamental group of a closed surface; it follows that $\pi_1(\Sigma')$ is free if and only if none of the free factors is the fundamental group of a closed surface of genus $\ge 1$.
Let me write a somewhat sketchy proof.
You can assume that each $\Sigma_i$ is disjoint from the boundary $\partial\Sigma$, because the inclusion maps $\Sigma_i \hookrightarrow\Sigma$ can be perturbed by isotopy to have images disjoint from $\partial\Sigma$. Once that is done, consider the compact subsurface $S \subset \Sigma$ which is complementary to the disjoint union $\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n\Sigma_i$:
$$S = \text{closure}\bigl(\Sigma - \bigsqcup_{i=1}^n\Sigma_i\bigr)
$$
Note that $S$ is quite possibly disconnected; let's write its component decomposition as $S = \sqcup_{j=1}^J S_j$. Note that $\partial S_j \cap \partial \Sigma$ may or may not be empty.
We have disjoint inclusions $\partial \Sigma_i \subset \partial S$ for $i=1,...,n$, and $\partial\Sigma_i$ is a union of components of $\partial S$.
Let $K$ be obtained from $S$ by attaching the cone of each $\partial\Sigma_i$, and so we have an inclusion $K \subset \Sigma'$.
The key is that $K$ is a deformation retraction of $\Sigma'$, and so $\pi_1(K) \approx \pi_1(\Sigma')$. This is the hard work of the sketch, which I'll omit.
Once you have $K$ in your hands, you can then observe that $K$ can be constructed in an alternate manner: it is (homeomorphic to) the quotient of $S$ by collapsing each subset $\partial \Sigma_i \subset \partial S$ to a single point $p_i$. Another way to describe this is that you first do a partial quotient by collapsing each component of $\partial S$ to a point, the result being a compact surface $S'$; and you then collapse certain finite subsets of $S'$ to single points to get $K$. One might say that $K$ is a "generalized wedge sum" of the components of $S'$, the "wedge points" being the $p_i$'s.
From this generalized wedge sum picture, you can then deduce the free factorization of the group $\pi_1(\Sigma') \approx \pi_1(K)$ that I started off with: for each component of the partial quotient $S'$ that is a closed surface, one obtains the fundamental group of that surface as a free factor; and from all the rest one obtains a free group as a free factor.

In summary, $\pi_1(\Sigma')$ is a free group if and only if no component $S'_j$ is a closed oriented surface of genus $\ge 1$ (some components might be $2$-spheres, coming from components of $S_j$ that are discs with boundary circle in $\partial\Sigma$).

For an example which has a free factor that is not a free group, start with $\Sigma$ as the closed oriented surface of genus $2$ with $1$ boundary component, and take one subsurface $\Sigma_1 \subset \Sigma$ such that $S = \text{closure}(\Sigma-\Sigma_1)$ has two subsurfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$: $S_1$ has genus $1$ and two boundary components, exactly one of which, denoted $c_1$, is in $\partial\Sigma_1$; and $S_2$ has genus $1$ and one boundary component $c_2$, which is in $\partial\Sigma_1$. The group $\pi_1(\Sigma')$ is a free product with two free factors: a rank $2$ free group (obtained from $S_1$ by collapsing $c_1$); and the group $\mathbb Z^2$ (obtained from $S_2$ by collapsing $c_2$).
